# Selenium - Chrome is not starting when I try to load an extension

Tags: google-chrome, gwt, selenium, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

Since Firefox does not support the GWT DevMode any more, I want to switch to Chrome for developing selenium tests for my application.

However, it fails to load the GWT-dev-plugin extension. The test does not return from

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Without configuring the extension, in works in the sense that a Chrome instance is at least started, however, without GWT plugin.

This is the way I configure the `webDriver`:

- package the GWT plugin of your Chrome installation (described here http://www.mythoughts.co.in/2013/09/seleinum-webdriver-loading-chrome.html#.U0ZTFFfKGno)
- use the path of the plugin `.crx` package as `pluginPath` in the following code

  ```
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addExtensions(new File(pluginPath));
  DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
  capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
  File driverExecutable = new File("test-selenium/chromedriver.exe");
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverExecutable.getAbsolutePath());
  driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
  ```

The only logging is a WARNING concerning the plugin key:

```
[14.899][WARNING]: Public key in crx header is different from key in manifest
key from header: ....

generated extension id from header key:   godampgacipeiboepncogmjpfbgcpfba 
generated extension id from manifest key: jpjpnpmbddbjkfaccnmhnkdgjideieim
```

Comment: How about running your tests in prod mode? How about SuperDevMode? The DevMode will soon stop to work in Chrome too, so IMO it's not worth fighting to make it work nowadays.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this and I still hope that this is not going to happen (like climate change or dead ;-) ). What I do not like about the superDevMode is that I have to use the browser for setting client-side breakpoints and that you have to recompile when you change client-side code which makes development much slower. For developing tests, I do not want to use prod mode because it is not just about writing test code but also about setting appropriate debug IDs for widgets. I would not like to recompile/deploy it each time.

Comment: Clarification: you do not need to “recompile” each time you change client-side code with SDM (as in “invoke the GWT compiler”), you just hit the _Dev Mode On_ bookmarklet, and SuperDevMode recompiles your code, which shouldn't be (much) slower than refreshing the page with DevMode.

Comment: Thanks: probably, I'll try it again with SuperDevMode. Currently, this still means staying with Chrome because FF does not support sourcemaps which is required to debug client-side code.

Anyway, I hope my question is still justified. I think this must have been worked once, mustn't it?

Comment: Firefox **does** support sourcemaps since 23.